# new version bzip2 ignored while installing R 3.4.0 in home directory in CentOS

Tags: r, unix, centos, configure, bzip2

I do not have enough permissions, so I need to install R3.4.0 in my home directory.

A newer version of bzip2 is required (>= 1.0.6)

The current version is v1.0.5

I've build bzip2 v1.0.6 in my home directory.

There are 4 directories in the build directory: bin, include, lib, man

I know I need to somehow modify paths, so I tried this:

```
PATH=path/to/bzip2-1.0.6_build/bin:$PATH
CPATH=path/to/bzip2-1.0.6_build/include:$CPATH
LIBRARY_PATH=path/to/bzip2-1.0.6_build/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path/to/bzip2-1.0.6_build/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

However, when I run ./configure to install R, I get the error:

```
checking if bzip2 version >= 1.0.6... no
checking whether bzip2 support suffices... configure: error: bzip2 library and headers are required
```

Which is the same error I got before installing bzip2 v1.0.6

But this time when I run `bzip2 --version` I get: 
`bzip2, a block-sorting file compressor.  Version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010.`
Which is correct.

How can I make it, so that in the `./configure` step, v1.0.6 is taken into acoount over v1.0.5?

Comment: Did you build the bzip2 shared library?  In the README file of bzip2: Do 'make -f Makefile-libbz2_so'. Check that `/bzip2/lib` contains libbz2.so or something like that.

Comment: Actually testing that myself.  It didn't help...